# Coffeescript - How to get for loop to loop over newly added elements in an array?

Tags: coffeescript

I need to loop over an array and add more elements to that array if needed. But coffeescript seems to terminate the loop at old length (where the array ended when the for loop started). I need the loop to loop over newly added elements. How do I fix this?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

for x in arr
    console.log(x + ">>>" + arr)    
    if(x < 3)
        arr.push(5)
```

Output on console:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9mhtvky/)

This doesnt seem to be a problem in js:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

for(i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
  if(arr[i] < 3)
    arr.push(5)
}
```

Output on console:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cv67a74/)

Comment: DON'T. Do not mutate the data structure you're iterating. That said, *look at the JavaScript*. If you look at the compiler output it will be very obvious why it behaves that way.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate the array you're iterating over. Split your algorithm to multiple segments, e.g.:

```coffee
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
to_add = []

# 1. Check for new items to add
for x in arr  
  if x < 3
    to_add.push(5)

# 2. Add the new items
arr = arr.concat(to_add)

# 3. Iterate over the array, including the new items    
for x in arr
  your_thing(x)
```